# iOS 3.0 Application Launch Issue

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

The application will run fine on an iPhone running iOS 2.0, but the application does not get past the splash screen on an iOS 3.0 device.

Please help me to get the tab bar loaded on the iPhone.

Comment: Maybe you use some specific in your app that refers to an older sdk?

Comment: Is there anything in the console log when you connect the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for reply,but on console nothing is getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

Have you change some default settings for iOS 3.0 ? if not then i think you should change all the setting in your application in order to iOS 3.0.